# getting javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly as response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

While automating REST api's using Jmeter 2.13, if a particular request's JSON response is very large in size I'm getting error as below.

```
*
```

> *javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:596)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940) 
>   at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:204)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:177)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:201)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:155)
>   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1745)
>   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:412)
>   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:352)
>   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
>   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
>   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)*

*

Comment: Can you run your script with JMetet 4?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried with JMeter 4 but got same error as in JMeter 2.13

Answer (score 0):

I guess view result tree is not able to handle the large response. Can you try below? In user.properties file add this:

```
view.results.tree.max_size=0
```

Restart Jmeter.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.Tried this but not resolved my issue.

Comment: And, here is my log info
READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 16408
handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]